# Integrator Circuit using Op-Amp Differentiator

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image: Op Amp differentiator circuit]

<sub>Source: http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp35.gif</sub>

This is an OpAmp differentiator circuit. Output is the derivative of Vin.

My question is: If I use output as input and Vin as output, would I get the integrated signal of input?

Comment: What makes you think that electronic circuits are fully reversible?

Comment: @JImDearden That was the question. I don't know if it is reversible or not. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not a good idea to drive the output of an op amp (which presents a low impedance to ground). The op amp would be fighting any circuit trying to drive its output -- an op amp will always try to drive its output to a certain value based on its inputs, but the output of the circuit that produces your \$V_{\text{in}}\$ would *also* try to drive the op amp's output to a likely different value. The circuit that would win the fight is the one that could drive more current. It's generally a bad idea to wire two analog outputs together.

If you need an integrator you can simply swap the resistor and capacitor with each other:

[image]

<sub>Source: [The Integrator Amplifier](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_6.html)</sub>

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I know the swapped version of it. What did you mean by "fighting"?

Comment: @FatihAydin See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, no. Consider the equivalent structure of an op amp as shown below. The op amp has an open-loop gain G, which is very big. It also has a closed-loop gain when it's used in negative feedback. But anyway let's just look at the following diagram where no feedback is applied. This is what you buy from stores. They give you something like this:

[image]

If you look carefully, the output of the op-amp is \$G.v_{in}\$, where \$v_{in}=v_+ - v_-\$, through some output resistance \$R_{out}\$. In practice, \$R_{out}\$ is very small but in ideal opamp models it's zero. Now as you see it only outputs the difference between its inputs multiplied by the open-loop gain G. It doesn't work in reverse. I mean, you can't put a voltage on the output and yet measure some voltage at its inputs. That's not designed to work like that.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*Figure 1. Internals of the ancient 741 opamp. Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier#Internal_circuitry_of_741-type_op-amp).*

From the internal schematic of the 741 op-amp it should be clear that the output can source current from the \$ V_{S+} \$ rail via Q14 or sink current to the \$ V_{S-} \$ rail via Q20. Nearly all (there are probably exceptions) opamps will have a similar push-pull arrangement on the output.

Notice, meanwhile, that the inputs (pins 2 and 3) are connected to the bases of transistors and this allows control of the amplifier.

The inputs can't be made to work as outputs and the outputs can't be made to work as inputs.